# Tracert with Port Number

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008

I have a windows 2008 r2 server on my companies network which is locked down and only allows certain ports through for specific ip addresses. so a simple tracert will not work for what I need since it does not allow for specifying a port. 
is there any applications out there that will provide similar results as tracert but allow you to specify port?

I am being told that the issue I am experiencing is outside of our network when I am almost certain it is inside our network but only way to prove it is with a trace to show where the packets are being dropped at.

Comment: Install any VPN on server for temporary and test it

Comment: How about tcptraceroute?

Comment: What is TCPTraceRoute?

Answer (score 2):

Windows implements tracert using ICMP echo packages. As such, you cannot change ports.